# Find outline of connected points in a plane

Tags: geometry

Please note that this is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137651/find-outline-of-n-points-in-a-plane) question but it is not the same question.

My situation is as follows:
I have an arbitrary amount of points on a 2D plane that are connected by an arbitrary amount of lines, following three rules:

- The number of lines connected to a point is divisible by 2 but never zero.
- The lines never cross each other.
- Every point is reachable from any other point

See this image for clarification:
[image: image on imgur]

I now want to find the outline of these lines which contains all of the other lines and points inside (marked in green in the image).

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137651/find-outline-of-n-points-in-a-plane) already but as far as I understand it this is not what I am searching for.
It would be cool if you could provide me with a theoretical way how you would do something like this.

Thanks!

-Moritz

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of all the constraints on the lines are.  Please explain.  It seems you want the Convex hull... yes?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: @DavidG.Stork well kind of, but also no. A convex hull basically outlines points, but I only want to use lines that are already defined.
As an example: Notice how a convex hull would connect points C and E in my picture but I do not want it to connect them because it can only use the predefined lines.
I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Ah... got it.  Let me think about this problem...

Comment: Points A and H are connected to three lines which not satisfy the first requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for does not necessarily exist.

(As an abstract point, you are essentially defining an eulerian planar graph, and asking for the cycle bounding the outer face. However, as stated above, this is not always feasible)

For example, consider the image below (make a point everywhere line direction changes). There is no curve that has an unambiguous 'inside' and 'outside' that contains all the points, unlike in the example you have included.

[image]

If you want to detect the boundary of the outer face regardless, here's a process that should work (with diagram illustrating):

1. Find the point in the plane with the minimum $x$ coordinate, call it $P_0$. This point must lie on the boundary of the outer face (if there are many such points, just pick one).
2. Consider the collection of all neighbors of $P_0$ (ie, points on a straight line with $P_0$). Pick out the neighbour with the smallest angle, taken clockwise from a horizontal line through $P_0$ that goes left (drawn in grey). In other words, sweep out a line from $P_0$, starting to the left of $P_0$, until you hit a neighbor. Call this neighbor $P_1$.
3. Find the neighbor of $P_1$ with the smallest clockwise angle from the line segment $[P_0, P_1]$, and call this neighbor $P_2$.
4. Repeat this process until you arrive back at $P_0$.

This process of always going clockwise should keep you on the 'outer' face, and all you need to know computationally is the coordinates of the points and which pairs of points are on a single line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Using the approach with the smallest angles was also an idea I had but I didn't know how to ensure that I go clockwise. This cleared things up. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to be of help ^^